# Unable to recreate the result

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I can't seem to figure out how to get the result shown below. Can someone please help me understand how to get this result?

$$P(red>0,black>0)=\sum_{r=1}^2\left(\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{\binom2r\binom2b\binom{26}{4-r-b}}{\binom{30}4}\right)=\frac{281}{5481}$$

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6fys.jpg).)

So, step by step, here is my math:

1. The result of the first Sigma is $3$
2. The result of the second Sigma is also $3$
3. The numbers for the numerator are $2\cdot 2\cdot 325=\binom21\binom21\binom{26}2$, giving a result of $1300$
4. The result for the denominator is $27405=\binom{30}4$
5. Now, multiplying 3 times the fraction $= \frac{3\cdot1300}{1\cdot27405}=\frac{3900}{27405}$.
6. So, now all that is left is $3$ times the fraction $3900/27405$, which results in $\frac{3\cdot 3900}{1\cdot 27405} = \frac{11700}{27405}$.

It's obvious that somehow, somewhere my math computing the numerator is wrong. I can see that $5481$ is the result of dividing $27405$ by $5$, but how the numerator result is supposed to be $281$ completely eludes me.

Can someone please be so kind and tell me where I went wrong? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you’ve badly misunderstood the summation notation. $\sum_{r=1}^2$ is not $3$; in fact, it means nothing by itself. If $f$ is some function of $r$, then $\sum_{r=1}^2f(r)$ is meaningful: it means $f(1)+f(2)$. And in your case the function $f$ is given by

$$f(r)=\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{\binom2r\binom2b\binom{26}{4-r-b}}{\binom{30}4}\;,$$

so you want

$$\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{\binom21\binom2b\binom{26}{4-1-b}}{\binom{30}4}+\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{\binom22\binom2b\binom{26}{4-2-b}}{\binom{30}4}=\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{2\cdot\binom2b\binom{26}{3-b}}{\binom{30}4}+\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{1\cdot\binom2b\binom{26}{2-b}}{\binom{30}4}\;.$$

Simlarly, $\sum_{b=1}^2$ means nothing by itself, but

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{2\binom2b\binom{26}{3-b}}{\binom{30}4}&=\frac{2\binom21\binom{26}{3-1}}{\binom{30}4}+\frac{2\binom22\binom{26}{3-2}}{\binom{30}4}\\\\
&=\frac{2\cdot2\cdot\binom{26}2}{\binom{30}4}+\frac{2\cdot1\cdot\binom{26}1}{\binom{30}4}\;.
\end{align*}$$

I’ll leave it to you to work out

$$\sum_{b=1}^2\frac{1\cdot\binom2b\binom{26}{2-b}}{\binom{30}4}$$

and finish the computation.

Comment: I thought I learned the meaning of Sigma from here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sigma-notation.html but, apparently I completely misunderstood. I'll work through your explanation, for which, along with the editing of my original post, I want to express my thanks, even though frowned upon (which I understand, but choose to knowingly ignore, since you did not such an outstanding job!). Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jürgen: You’re very welcome. Feel free to leave a question here if you run into trouble sorting it out.

Comment: Just to add some context to the above example, it is supposed to compute the probability of drawing AT LEAST one red ball and AT LEAST one black ball from an Urn filled with 30 balls, where 26 balls are white, 2 are red and 2 are black, having drawn 4 balls at random without replacement.

So, the chance of having at least one red and at least one black when grabbing 4 random balls from the urn, is ~5.12%. Is this correct? (It seems so low, considering the fact that we also included the case of drawing 2 red and 1 black, or 2 black and 1 red, and even 2 black and 2 red)

Comment: @Jürgen: Yes, that appears to be correct. The reason that it’s so low is that there are so many white balls: you’re very likely to get $3$ or $4$ white balls, and even if you get only $2$, there’s still one chance in $3$ that the other two will be the same color.

Comment: In fact, if I am not mistaken, I just tried to compute the probability of getting EXACTLY one red and EXACTLY one black ball when drawing 4 random balls without replacement, and it seems to be 4.74%, so I assume the above is correct. 2 choose 1 times 2 choose 1 times 26 choose 2 divided by 30 choose 4 = 1300 / 27405 = ~4.74%

Comment: @Jürgen: That’s right (apart from the typo: your second ‘2 choose 2’ was clearly intended to be ‘2 choose 1’).

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. Thanks again for your time and patience!

Comment: @Jürgen: You’re welcome!